# Pausing std::thread until a function finishes

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

```
class Class {
public:
    Class ();
private:
    std::thread* updationThread;
};
```

Constructor:

```
Class::Class() {
    updationThread = new std::thread(&someFunc);
}
```

At some point in my application, I have to pause that thread and call a function and after execution of that function I have to resume the thread. Let's say it happens here:

```
void Class::aFunction() {
     functionToBeCalled(); //Before this, the thread should be paused
     //Now, the thread should be resumed.
}
```

I have tried to use another thread with function `functionToBeCalled()` and use `thread::join` but was unable to do that for some reason.

How can I pause a thread or how can I use `thread::join` to pause a thread until the other finishes?

Comment: What is that other thread doing? Can you play with the body of `someFunc`? "Pausing" a thread is not a normal operation.

Comment: STL does not provide this. In Windows, you could use SuspendThread.

Comment: @user7116 I can. The reason I wanna do it is because when `functionToBeCalled()` and the thread work together, I am having internal problems.

Comment: @khajvah: you'll need to elaborate on what "internal problems" are. Simply pausing `someFunc` will not guarantee you will no longer have internal problems. In fact, it will most likely cause new problems.

Comment: What you have described above is an attempted solution to some problem, that doesn't work, and you are asking how to write your solution.  However, your problem isn't the above question, but rather the above is an attempted solution to your real problem.  When asking a question on stack overflow, include both your attempted solution (what have you tried?), and a description of the underlying problem that your attempted solution was motivated by.  In this case, your attempted solution is fundamentally misguided, and we need your underlying problem to point out how to solve it.

Comment: @Yakk I understand what you are saying but when you have absolutely no idea on some topic (multithread in this case), you cannot even attempt a solution. Believe me, I have tried to find some ways to do this but I didn't succeed. I appreciate your and my time (assuming doing myself would be faster than waiting for an answer) too, so I wouldn't just ask somebody to solve my problems without attempting.

Comment: @kahjvah I have many ideas on how to solve multithreaded programming problems.  But you aren't describing a problem, but rather a failed solution.  You need to describe the *actual problem* that motivated your failed solution.

Comment: @Yakk I wasn't saying you have no idea about multithreading. When I said `when you have absolutely no idea on some topic (multithread in this case), you cannot even attempt a solution.` I meant me, it was kind of a way to illustrate a situation.

Comment: @Yakk My idea on stackoverflow is a little different. I try to ask questions that might be helpful for others in future. If I described my problem and got a solution, it wouldn't be helpful for anyone but me. But in this case, there might be some people who would want to pause and continue `std::thread`

Comment: @khajvah: the unfortunate bit is you generalized your question to where it can't possibly solve your actual problem! We really do like specific problems :)

Comment: @user7116 Anyways, this might not solve my problem but this is helpful  at least... Solving my problem is my duty and I might use this method(which will work but will create some bugs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can easily (in a standard way) "pause" some thread, and then resumes it. I imagine you can send SIGSTOP and SIGCONT if you are using some Unix-flavored OS, but otherwise, you should properly mark the atomic parts inside `someFunc()` with mutexes and locks, an wraps `functionToBeCalled()` with a lock on the corresponding mutex:

```
std::mutex m; // Global mutex, you should find a better place to put it
              // (possibly in your object)
```

and inside the function:

```
void someFunc() {
    // I am just making up stuff here
    while(...) {
        func1();

        {
           std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m); // lock the mutex
           ...; // Stuff that must not run with functionToBeCalled()
        } // Mutex unlocked here, by end of scope
    }
}
```

and when calling `functionToBeCalled()`:

```
void Class::aFunction() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m); // lock the mutex
    functionToBeCalled();
} // Mutex unlocked here, by end of scope
```

Comment: More importantly, *you do not want to "pause" it*. If `A` cannot be running while `B` is running, they must share some data dependency. Simply pausing the thread executing `A` does not guarantee that `B` will run when `A` is in an appropriate and/or consistent state w.r.t. data dependencies (i.e. protecting the section dealing with the shared data is the right answer).

Comment: @user7116 My thread simple catches a signal when a file is modified. I use it to know when the file is modified outside the application. The function modifies the file. It writes some things to file and after it writes first string, the thread works and the application crashes because the function does not write everything to the file

Comment: @user7116 when the function finishes writing everything to the file, I don't think the crash will happen.

Comment: @khajvah: bingo, an actionable problem statement! I suggest modifying your question to include this pertinent information regarding why exactly you need to coordinate `someFunc` and `functionToBeCalled`. lvella's answer is pretty good and may solve your problem provided the only place which updates your file is your code.

Comment: If your file will be written by external sources (what seems the case, otherwise you wouldn't need to listen for changes), and if crashes when you write yourself, thus it will crash, too, if someone else writes... you must rework your code to not crash on incomplete writes, but instead, wait for the full write.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a condition variable. An example similar to your situation is given there:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable